# Bootstrap Responsive Grid Issue on iPhone / Mobile device

Tags: android, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I am finishing up a website which can be found here - [www.minimindsacademy.com](http://www.minimindsacademy.com)

I need to find a way for the height to take up 100% of the screen on an iPhone device. It is not taking up 100% height on my iPhone but on my desktop browser it is even if I shrink it. The goal of this site was for it to be 100% responsive with the use of Twitter Bootstrap as my style framework. I am not sure if it is doing this on other mobile devices. Also, I cannot replicate this on my browser screen (when I make the browser screen small as possible it looks fine, however on my iPhone the height isn't 100%).I don't know if I did something wrong with the CSS or what.

It won't let me post images on my posts yet, but if you view the site on a mobile device you should see an example of what I am referring to on the Home page.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <!-- HEAD -->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Home</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-
BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<section class="hero">
    <!--Nav Bar-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-
toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-
controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="home.html">Welcome</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="staff.html">Staff</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span4"></div>
      <div class="span4">           
        <a href="home.html" >
          <img id="logo" src="assets/logo.png" alt="logo">
        </a></div>
      <div class="span4"></div>
    </div>
</div>


<!--BOX START-->
<div class="container" id="box">
    <!--HEADER-->
    <!--<h1>Home</h1>-->
    <!-- CARASOUL -->
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="assets/home/1.jpg" alt="Chania">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Jammin Out</h3>
            <p>Piano at the mall!</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="assets/home/2.jpg" alt="Chicago">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Snack Time</h3>
            <p>Healthy eating for everyone!</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="assets/home/3.jpg" alt="Chicago">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Comfortable Environment</h3>
            <p>Hangin with my pal!</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="assets/home/4.jpg" alt="Chicago">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Arts and Crafts</h3>
            <p>Chalk is always fun!</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="assets/home/5.jpg" alt="Chicago">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Backyard Activities</h3>
            <p>Beep Beep!</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="assets/home/6.jpg" alt="Chicago">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Outdoor Fun</h3>
            <p>Hangin at the park!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-
slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true">
</span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel"  role="button" data-
slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true">
</span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

    <!-- MAIN -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4" id="one">
                    <h3>About us</h3>
                    <p>Mini Minds Academy is here to provide a nurturing, 
safe and stimulating environment for children to explore, learn and play! We 
respect and value the diversity in each child's character, background and 
level of development.</p>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" 
href="about.html">Read more</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" id="two">
                    <h3>Meet our staff</h3>
                    <p>Our staff at Mini Minds academy consist of teachers 
Shelly Lenzotti, an alumni of Boise State University. She has over 13 years 
of experience in educating and caing for children ages 3 months - 11 years 
of age.</p>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" 
href="staff.html">Meet us</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" id="three">
                    <h3>Contact us</h3>
                    <p>If you are interested in our program and have a child 
between te ages of 1-6 years old feel free to contact us. We would be happy 
to provide for your child's needs if we have space available!</p>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" 
href="contact.html">Contact us</a>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
</section>

<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script 
src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
        .navbar-brand {
            padding: 5px 15px;
        }

        .navbar-brand img {
            height: 40px;
        }

        #headerTitle {
            position: relative;
            max-width: 75%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }


        .carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
            background-image: none
        }

        #myCarousel {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        section.hero {
            background-image: url("../assets/1.jpg");
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            width: 100%;

        }


        #logo {
            max-width: 400px;
            margin: auto auto;
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            width:100%;
        }

        .row .span4 {
            text-align: center;
        }

        #box {
            max-width: 75%;
            padding: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 100px;
        }

        .row {
            padding: 0px 20px 0 20px;
        }

        .col-md-8 {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #717070;
            padding-bottom:20px;
        }

        .col-md-4 {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: white;
            padding-bottom:20px;
        }

        #about h5 {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        #about2 {
            background-color: #945389;
            font-weight: bold;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #one {
            background-color: #ee4524;
        }

        #two {
            background-color: #a2c95c;
        }

        #three {
            background-color: #945389;
        }

        .btn-primary {
          color: white;
          background-color: #018ca9;
          border-color: #018ca9;
          width: 100%;
          margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .btn-primary:hover,
        .btn-primary:focus,
        .btn-primary:active,
        .btn-primary.active {
          color: white;
          background-color: #01778f;
          border-color: #01778f;
        }

        h1 {
            color:#945389;
            font-weight:bold;
        }

        @media only screen and 
          (max-width: 767px) {
              #box{max-width:100%;}
        }
```

I figured it out, it is because I am using domain-forwarding with go-daddy. The masking is converting the code into this:

```
 <html>

<head>
  <title>minimindsacademy.com</title>

</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://www.ayodlomedia.com/miniminds/home.html" 
frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>

<!-- pageok -->
<!-- 11 -->
<!-- -->
</html>
```

Apparently the frameset tag isn't compatible with HTML5, thus, I am assuming thats where the error is coming from.

Comment: Post your code with the problem.  Additionally, a picture of what's actually happening and a picture or description of what you want would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say I need to find a way for the height to take up 100% of the screen on an iPhone device. It is not taking up 100% height on my iPhone but on my desktop browser it is even if I shrink it. I don't think I am allowed to post images yet.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your hero section just doesn't get enough height to fill the screen. If you add min-height: 100vh to the .hero class that makes the background fill the screen.

Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: Simon, thats whats weird this is already in my CSS

    section.hero {
        height: 100vh;
    }

The screen height is working on everything except my iPhone.

Comment: Not on the live site you linked to... Maybe your just getting cached css on the iPhone?

Comment: Interesting that worked for Chrome in my browser and fixed the issue on my iPhone (Safari), but now in Firefox on my desktop browser its cutting off after the height of my screen.

Comment: That sounds like height: 100vh. Make sure you use min-height and do a hard refresh Ctrl + F5 (Windows) / ⌘ + Shift + R (Mac) to clear the cache.

Comment: It had to do with godaddy converting my original html into framesets. I edited the original post. Thanks for your help.